# how give a link to an Elementor Pro widget with variable part

Tags: links, buttons, sharing

I'm trying to give link to one button in Elementor like this **(for sharing the post on a social media site)**:

```
https://eitaa.com/share/url?url={url}
```

by {url} I mean the current post url. but when I put this as link for button it doesn't work
anyone can help?

Comment: You would be best suited to ask the Elementor Development team/support channel.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.